# Makefile: modifying stem in pattern rule

Tags: makefile

I have files in directories called `data` and `helpers`, and I would like to use both of them to create target files in `result`.

The directory structure is the following:

```
data
 + A
 | + file1
 | + file2
 | + ...
 + B
 | + file1
 ...
helpers
 + file1
 + file2
 ...
```

The directory structure in `result` is the same as in `data`. Therefore, I would like to write the following rule:

```
result/%: data/% helpers/% script
    script $@ $(word 1,$^) $(word 2,$^)
```

The problem with this is that `file1`, `file2`, etc. in the `helpers` directory are not in the subdirectory.

I have now got the following options:

- write a separate rule for every subdirectory (impractical, there are 20)
- do a `foreach` including every subdirectory to create the rule (how can I access the prerequisite list then?)

However, I would much rather write one of the following:

```
result/%: data/% helpers/$(basename %) # this doesn't work
result/%: data/% helpers/$(basename $*) # this doesn't work either
```

Is there any way to modify a pattern in the rule declaration by modifying the stem it matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do what you want is to enable [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion) in your makefile.

Example:

> Note that the directory prefix (D), as described in Implicit Rule Search Algorithm, is appended (after expansion) to all the patterns in the prerequisites list. As an example:
>
> .SECONDEXPANSION:
>
> /tmp/foo.o:
>
> ```
> %.o: $$(addsuffix /%.c,foo bar) foo.h
>         @echo $^
> ```
>
> The prerequisite list printed, after the secondary expansion and directory prefix reconstruction, will be /tmp/foo/foo.c /tmp/bar/foo.c foo.h. If you are not interested in this reconstruction, you can use $$* instead of % in the prerequisites list.

So something like this should work (untested):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
result/%: data/% helpers/$$(notdir %)
```

make's `basename` is not the same as the shell's `basename` (that **constantly** trips me up).

If you wanted to use `$(foreach)` though you would want something like (untested):

```
define dirrule
result/$1/%: data/$1/% helpers/%
        @echo cmd 1
        @echo cmd 2
endef

$(foreach dir,subdir1 subdir2 ... subdir20,$(eval $(call dirrule,$(dir))))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the secondary expansions quite yet. How would they look like to achieve what I'm trying to do in the example above? And for the `$(foreach ...)`, how can I add the actual rules (the syntax does not seem to support newlines)?

Comment: Edited with examples for both uses.

Comment: Yes, this works. Don't know what I did wrong before. Thank you!